# Getting Arduino to work in raspberry pi with ubuntu server

Tags: server, usb, raspberrypi, arduino

I have a raspberry pi 4b with ubuntu server (21.10) installed. I'd like it to communicate with an arduino uno r3. I have the following problem, the arduino, while detected by `lsub` it doesn't have an associated file under `dev`. The server has got an xfce desktop environment and I have installed the arduino IDE v1.8 for arm64 from the website. The IDE is working and I've run the linux-setup script correctly.

When I run `lsusb` the output is

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
```

and when I run `ls /dev/ttyACM* /dev/ttyUSB*`

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyACM*': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory
```

The output of `sudo udevadm monitor -u` is:

```
UDEV  [334.511980] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [334.518796] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [334.522288] add      /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [334.529389] bind     /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2 (usb)
```

and of `journalctl --follow` (only the relevant parts)

```
Dec 18 13:31:53 Etheria kernel: usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Dec 18 13:31:53 Etheria kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043, bcdDevice= 0.01
Dec 18 13:31:53 Etheria kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
Dec 18 13:31:53 Etheria kernel: usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
Dec 18 13:31:53 Etheria kernel: usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 55736303939351714262
```

(Etheria is the name of the raspberry pi)

Any ideas on what might be happening?

For contrast the Arduino is detected perfectly on my computer (Linux, but OpenSuse) with the same cable.

**Edit**

Couldn't get it to work on time on ubuntu so I tried manjaro (for arm64) and it could  detect the arduino. I think it's some package that is not by default on the server install, if somebody figures that out, please post.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you run these on separate terminal and report output when you plug in Arduino: `sudo udevadm monitor -u` and `journalctl --follow`

Comment: Of course, adding it to the main question @user.dz

Comment: I am not familiar with raspberry pi but some distributions put `cdc-acm` driver/module in `linux-modules-extra` package. Could you check if it is the case?

Comment: Ok, it wasn't `linux-modules-extra`, which I had already tried, but it was `linux-modules-extra-raspi` which I hadn't tried for some reason. Thanks a lot. Do you want to publish the answer?

Comment: You could submit the answer, I am here for help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user.dz we figured out which package was missing. It was missing the `linux-modules-extra-raspi`. It is a rather large package that contains most of the modules you might be missing from an electronics boards such as i2c and others.